# Maintaining layout of Tikz diagrams with TeX4ht (converting as single pictures)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht

A Tikz diagram such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) node[draw] (A) {A};
    \path (2,0) node[draw] (B) {B};
    \draw (A) -- (B) node[midway,above = 0 em] {via};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

when processed with (pdf)LaTeX gives

[image]

while using TeX4ht extracts only the text, giving a conversion to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)"> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)"> 
<!-- html --> 
<meta name="src" content="test.tex"> 
<meta name="date" content="2011-11-17 09:21:00"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"> 
</head><body>
<!--l. 8--><p class="noindent" > ABvia

</body></html>
```

With more complex Tikz input, TeX4ht turns *parts* of the picture into separate `.png` files. What is the best way to get TeX4ht to convert the entire Tikz environment into a single graphic in the output? I've already tried using the Tikz externaliation library, but this does not compile successfully. (Note: Output as for example an SVG would also be fine - the key thing it to maintain the layout.)

---

For clarity, the result of trying to use externalization with Tikz is:

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'latex -halt-on-error -interact
ion=batchmode -jobname "test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{test}\input{tes
t}" && dvips -o "test-figure0".ps "test-figure0".dvi' ========

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'latex -halt-on-error -interaction
=batchmode -jobname "test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{test}\input{test}"
 && dvips -o "test-figure0".ps "test-figure0".dvi' did NOT result in a usable o
utput file 'test-figure0' (expected one of .epsi:.eps:.ps:). Please verify that
 you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'.
 Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the com
mand simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'test-figure0.log'. If you c
ontinue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 \end{tikzpicture}

?
```

The diagram is part of a larger page, so the aim to to process the text part as normal but have the Tikz part treated differently (as a picture or as an SVG: whatever is better).

Comment: Do you mean that externalisation doesn't compile when run using TeX4ht?  When I'm trying to get png's, then I run the externalisation with ordinary LaTeX to get them.  The difficulty with SVG output is that it doesn't do mixed text and graphics all that well.  What's the desired outcome?  A *single* document consisting of just the picture, or the diagram embedded in a larger (HTML) document?

Comment: @AndrewStacey See edit on externalization (which works fine for pdfLaTeX with appropriate settings). I'm not too fussed about whether the graphic is in SVG or `.png` format (although I've been told that SVG is the future). I can use a script to do multiple runs if necessary, but was rather hoping to set up the `.tex` file such that TeX4ht did the entire job itself. An answer showing an appropriate workflow using standard LaTeX plus TeX4ht would, I think, also be valid.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is specialized output driver for use with tex4ht in Tikz. Using it, diagrams are saved in SVG.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) node[draw] (A) {A};
    \path (2,0) node[draw] (B) {B};
    \draw (A) -- (B) node[midway,above = 0 em] {via};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent - I'd been looking at this from the TeX4ht end, and did not think about the `pgf` end. Now all I have to do is get it to work with the real problem ...

Comment: this mode has some restrictions, see pgf manual section 10.2.4 (I have version from tlcontrib, I hope it is the same in version from ctan)

Comment: I've narrowed my other issues down to using `\shortstack` inside a node to have multi-line text. That does not seem to work (a `tabular` also breaks the SVG file entirely). However, I can probably put up with this.

Comment: I'd suggest another wrinkle: include this driver only if tex4ht is used:  `\ifx\HCode\UnDef\else\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}\fi`

Comment: @Boris In the [real case](https://github.com/uktug/latex-beginners-course), this is not an issue. I have a number of different target formats, and each one has a short custom `.tex` file before converging on a single main body. So the driver selection can go in the online-only `.tex` file.

Comment: @joseph-wright This depends on your preferred compilation routine.  I tend to have one master file and put all customization for different output formats in my `Makefile`s, and you prefer to have short headers with customization.  For my method `\ifx\HCode` is very useful.

Comment: @Boris I like to keep the TeX in `.tex` files :-) I'm not a big fan of Makefiles, etc., for documents (they are fine for package development). I like to be able to run things in my editor in the main: that gets a bit awkward with creating HTML files.

Comment: This interests me and I tried the answer from @michal.h21 to no avail.  My html file contains "ABvia 1".  The line `\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}` does not compile.  Where should start to look, or must I start a totally new question?

Comment: @Louis maybe post new question with detailed error messages and details on how you compile the file

Comment: @Louis also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158921/2891 for another method of conversion and including svg from tikz. it is little bit more difficult, but the results may be better than results of the method described in this answer

Answer (score 1):

To get the whole `.tex` into SVG use `dvisvgm`. Unlike `dvipng` it knows about PStricks and whatnot. It does an awesome job on TeX-Files with PGF.

```
latex file.tex
dvisvgm file.dvi
```

...and ready is your `file.svg`.

I could not get `tex4ht` going on many PGF files from [texample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/), but `dvisvgm` worked. The outdated version 1.9.2 from Ubuntu 16.04 had some glitches (ligatures like “fi” and “ff” turned Chinese), but the 2.0.4 was great.