# how to create non linear presentation using beamer or prosper

Tags: beamer

8eamer prosper produces slides like power-point. Is it possible to produce non-linear presentation like the one produced by prezi?

Comment: What do you mean with non-linear?

Comment: Something like [`lecturer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lecturer)? I only know it exists. I've never used nor seen a presentation with it.