# Properly layering/structuring a document

Tags: data-structures, layers, structure

I'm creating a kind of convoluted document. The idea is that I begin with a certain concept, say

section 1

Food

Food can then be then divided into many categories

section 1
subsection 1

Meat

section 1
subsection 2

Vegetables

Then for each of those subsections i can go into even more details. Let's consider meat:

section 1
subsection 1
subsubsection 1

Chicken

section 1
subsection 1
subsubsection 2

Pork

Even further, I want to continue nesting the subsubsections with paragraphs, etc.

The point is that a reader would like to learn how to cook say a chicken soup. I would expect him to read about carrots, celery and chicken. But then since the soup could be placed in both the vegetables and meat section, I don't really know where to put it.

My question is the following:
How would you structure this document? Maybe a use of hyperlinks would be beneficial for this task? An idea that I have in mind is to build a graph, where all these concepts are joined by links and each node is a hyperlink to the content it considers. Maybe some other software than LaTeX would be useful? (Keep in mind that I need LaTeX for the type setting since in reality all those chicken soups are mathematical concepts.)

All hints will be appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I think something like the online tool 'Prezi' is something I'm looking for, but it seems a bit inconvenient to work purely with that. Any alternatives?

Comment: I think I've found what I was looking for under this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50213/latex-article-to-prezi-style-zooming-dia-presention