# Can I use TikZ (instead of PSTricks) for latex2html5?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, latex2html

I found this today:

http://latex2html5.com/

> Author interactive math equations and diagrams online using LATEX and PSTricks

It looks nice, but I'm more familiar with *TikZ*. Is anybody aware of something equivalent which is not based on *PSTricks* but *TikZ*?

Comment: you can use tex4ht for this job - http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35145/2891 for tex4ht + tikz, http://www.albany.edu/~hammond/demos/Html5/arXiv/ for tex4ht + mathjax + html5

Comment: You need to know that not all PSTricks constructs are currently supported. The author probably chose PSTricks because it is much less verbose compared to TikZ. Parsing TikZ is much more complicated.

Comment: @michal.h21 Do you mind cooking up the simplest example with tex4ht?

Comment: @percusse not really the simples example, because I added also other features, but I added something :)

Answer (score 8):

There is simple example which shows usage of `tikz-to-svg`, `mathjax` and `webfonts` with `tex4ht`.

First some sample document:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, myexternalize, myfontspec, mathtools}
\setmainfont{STIXGeneral}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}


First, show me some inline math: 
\(\forall x \in X, \quad \exists y \leq \epsilon\)

Now some display math:

\[
    \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \binom{n}{k}
\]

And finally, some tikz picture, source is some answer on TeX.sx:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Time axis
    \draw (0,0) -- node[below=1cm] {Time $\to$} (6,0);
    % Emotional axis
    \draw (0,0) -- node[left] {\parbox{2cm}{\centering $\uparrow$ \\ Emotional \\ intensity}} (0,4);
    % Time ticks
    \foreach \x [count=\j] in {0.2,3,4.5,6} {
        \draw (\x,0) coordinate (t\j) -- (\x,-0.1cm) node[below] (tt\j) {Time \j};
    }
    \node[below] at (tt1.south) {(Emotional event)};
    % Curves
    \draw (t1) .. controls +(1,2) .. node[above right] {Experienced} (t2);
    \draw[dashed] (t1) .. controls +(1,4) .. node[above right] {Predicted} (t4);
\end{tikzpicture}

Some samples \textit{of font} \textbf{changes} and diacritics: Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.
\end{document}
```

Two custom packages are used, `myexternalize` and `myfontspec`. These packages tries to resolve issues of `fontspec` and `tikz-externalize` with `tex4ht`.

Now we should show these packages. `myexternalize.sty`:

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{
    tex4ht inc/.style={
        /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
            \includegraphics[]{##1.svg}%
        }

    }
}

\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
    \tikzexternalize[mode=only graphics]
        \tikzset{tex4ht inc}
}{
    \tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzset{
 external/system call/.add={}                                                
      {; inkscape -z -f "\image.pdf" -l "\image.svg"
            }    
}
    \tikzexternalize
}
```

this package uses `lualatex` to convert `tikz` pictures to `pdf` and `inkscape` to convert these `pdf` to  `svg`. Some details can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158921/2891) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165997/2891). You also need file `myexternalize.4ht`, which configures `tex4ht` to include `svg` images:

```
\Configure{graphics*}  
         {svg}{  
          {\Configure{Needs}{File: \Gin@base.svg}\Needs{}}
          \Picture[\csname a:GraphicsAlt\endcsname]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.svg \csname a:Gin-dim\endcsname}%  
         }
```

Now we need to handle fonts, with package `myfontspec.sty`:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \newcommand\setmainfont[1]{}
  \newcommand\setmathfont[1]{}  
}{
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
}
```

This file only loads `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages and defines some dummy commands when compiled with `tex4ht`, `fontspec` is used otherwise. Now you can compile your document to get `svg` images:

```
lualatex -shell-escape filename
```

Now we need to provide some configurations for mathjax and webfonts for `tex4ht`. File `myconfig.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml, mathml}
% Configure for mathjax
\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript"\Hnewline
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"\Hnewline
></script>\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\AddFontFace[4]{%
\Css{@font-face {
    font-family: #1;
    src: local("#2"),
        url('#3');
    #4
 }}
\special{t4ht+@File: #3}
}
\edef\CurrentFontFamily{rmfamily}
\newcommand\SetFontFamily[1]{
\edef\CurrentFontFamily{#1}
}
\newcommand\NormalFont[2]{\AddFontFace{\CurrentFontFamily}{#1}{#2}{font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}}

\newcommand\BoldFont[2]{\AddFontFace{\CurrentFontFamily}{#1}{#2}{font-weight: bold;font-style: normal;}}
\newcommand\ItalicFont[2]{\AddFontFace{\CurrentFontFamily}{#1}{#2}{font-weight: normal;font-style: italic;}}
\newcommand\BoldItalicFont[2]{\AddFontFace{\CurrentFontFamily}{#1}{#2}{font-weight: bold;font-style: italic;}}

\NormalFont{STIXDefault}{STIXGeneral-Regular.woff}
\BoldFont{STIXDefault}{STIXGeneral-Bold.woff}
\ItalicFont{STIXDefault}{STIXGeneral-Italic.woff}
\BoldItalicFont{STIXDefault}{STIXGeneral-BoldItalic.woff}
\Css{body{font-family:rmfamily, "STIXDefault", sans-serif;}}
\EndPreamble
```

There are definitions for `mathjax` before  `\begin{document}`, after that, definitions for fonts follow. I created new command `\AddFontFace` which add font definition to the `css` file, and number of commands for including files for different font weights and styles. `Stix fonts` are used, because these fonts are used by `mathjax`, so it looks good when they are used also for text. You need to copy used `.woff` files from zip file provided on [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stixfonts/).

Now we can compile the document with:

```
htlatex filename "myconfig, mathml, charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

Resulting pdf:

[image]

and html:

[image]

you can also see the [html page in action](http://michal-h21.github.io/samples/sebastian/html5.html).