# Convert PGFplot to html?

Tags: pgfplots, tex4ht, html

I'd like to convert a simple piece of LaTeX code which is basically some text with some centered graphs in between. This is a dummy version of the code I'd like to convert to HTML:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar stacked,
            ymin=0, ymax=35,
            width=9cm,
            height=6cm,
            symbolic x coords={Zimbabwe, France, Italy, Kenya, Germany},
            xtick=data,
            bar width=15pt,
            axis lines*=left,
            ytick={0,5,...,35},
            xticklabel style={
                text height=1.5ex,font=\footnotesize
            },
            yticklabel style={
                font=\footnotesize
            },
            ymajorgrids,
            xlabel={ ... ... ... ... ... , 2004-2009},
            xlabel style={yshift=5.8cm,xshift=.9cm},
            ]
            \addplot[fill=gray!50] coordinates {
                (Zimbabwe,16)
                (France,30)
                (Italy,10)
                (Kenya,5)
                (Germany,20)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I tired with `latex4ht`, which I used in the past, but it seems that it does not work with the PGFplot code.

So my question is: how do you convert PGFplot graphs to html? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Related, or possibly duplicate: [How can I use TikZ to make standalone (SVG) graphics?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51757/how-can-i-use-tikz-to-make-standalone-svg-graphics)

Comment: for method of conversion of tikz environments to svg, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158921/2891

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of ways to get html and svg graphics with `tikz` and `tex4ht`. In my opinion, best way is to use `tikz externalization` library to do the conversion. With this library, standalone `pdf` image is created for every `tikz` picture, and some external command can then be used to convert this `pdf` image to `svg`. I had great success with `inkscape` doing this job, with other applications, like `imagemagick` I found some problems and result was not correct. So you need to install `inkscape` in order to get this working.

First, create package which will set `externalization` for us, `myexternalize.sty`:

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{
    tex4ht inc/.style={
        /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
            \includegraphics[]{##1.svg}%
        }

    }
}

\tikzset{
 external/system call/.add={}                                                
      {; inkscape -z -f "\image.pdf" -l "\image.svg"
            }    
}
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
    \tikzexternalize[mode=only graphics]
    \tikzset{tex4ht inc}
}{
    \tikzexternalize
}
```

This package creates new `tikz` style, `tex4ht inc`, which will be used with `tex4ht`. With `pdflatex`, `pdf` file is exported and `inscape` is called in command line mode to convert this `pdf` image to `svg`.

Now we need some configuration for `tex4ht`, in order to be able to include `svg` images, file `myexternalize.4ht`:

```
\Configure{graphics*}  
         {svg}{  
          {\Configure{Needs}{File: \Gin@base.svg}\Needs{}}
          \Picture[\csname a:GraphicsAlt\endcsname]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.svg \csname a:Gin-dim\endcsname}%  
         }
```

now you can include `myexternalize` package in your document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{myexternalize}
....
```

and then compile the document with

```
pdflatex -shell-escape documentname
```

to get `svg` files. `-shell-escape` option is important, otherwise conversion cant work! now you can compile file to html:

```
htlatex documentname
```

you can see the result [here](http://michal-h21.github.io/samples/jenny/sample.html)