# Can't include diagram with tex4ebook

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook

I would like to convert a scientific book with lots of formulas and tables to `epub3`. So far I have read all the posts that are tagged and related to `tex4ebook`, `tex4ht` etc. and I have managed to produce an `epub3` version of my book with the formulas looking ok.

So far my command is:

```
tex4ebook  -f epub3  filename  mathml
```

Now, suppose that my tex has the following tikzpicture (borrowed from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145585/can-i-use-tikz-instead-of-pstricks-for-latex2html5/166061#166061)).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Time axis
    \draw (0,0) -- node[below=1cm] {Time $\to$} (6,0);
    % Emotional axis
    \draw (0,0) -- node[left] {\parbox{2cm}{\centering $\uparrow$ \\     Emotional \\ intensity}} (0,4);
    % Time ticks
    \foreach \x [count=\j] in {0.2,3,4.5,6} {
        \draw (\x,0) coordinate (t\j) -- (\x,-0.1cm) node[below] (tt\j)     {Time \j};
    }
    \node[below] at (tt1.south) {(Emotional event)};
    % Curves
    \draw (t1) .. controls +(1,2) .. node[above right] {Experienced} (t2);
    \draw[dashed] (t1) .. controls +(1,4) .. node[above right]    {Predicted} (t4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am not able (or I do not understand how to do it), to use `tex4ebook` to get the `epub` to contain the above image. What should I add to the previous command for the `tikzpicture` to show? I have succeeded in completing all the instructions in all the relative `tex4ebook` `StackExchange` tags and be able to produce for example a `pdf` with `luatex` that contains the above image, but I do not know what to do to make it work with the `tex4ebook` command.

Can anyone tell me the steps I have to take? Thank you

Comment: Most likely, externalizing the `tikz` picture somewhere else and using it in your real document by `\includegraphics` is a better approach?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it is, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158921/2891 for example.

Comment: the svg file is inserted in epub file, but the problem is that it is not valid xml, there is some syntax error. Tikz support for SVG is fragile unfortunately, using externalization is better

Comment: `@Christian + michal`, Thank you both for your replies. `@michal`, thank you for `tex4ebook`. So do you think externalization should be applied also to figures of this form too?:                                            \begin{figure}[H]\hspace*{\fill}%
\begin{game}{2}{2}[$t_1=S$]
 & $F$ & $NF$\\
 $F$ &$1$, -$2$ &$2$, -$1$\\
 $NF$ &-$1$, $2$ &$0, 0$ \\
\end{game}\hspace*{10mm}%
\begin{game}{2}{2}[$t_1=W$]
 & $F$ & $NF$\\
 $F$ &-$1,1$ &$2$, -$1$ \\
 $NF$ &$0, 2$ &$0, 0$\\
\end{game}\hspace*{\fill}%
 \caption[]{\textit{A game with incomplete information}}
\end{figure}%(using `sgame` package).

Comment: `@michal`:Does externalization excludes the usage of `mathml`? If no, how can I use it, cause so far steo 1. is to use `pdflatex -shell-escape filename`, 2. `htlatex filename myconfig` (I do not know if running `htlatex filename myxonfig xhtml` makes any improvements). Btw I think there is a bug in [your answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158921/2891) for extarnalization: `{; inkscape -z -f "\image.pdf" -l "\image.svg"}` should be `; inkscape -z -f "\image.pdf" -l "\image.svg"` (just delete the brackets, otherwise the svgs you are producing have an `}` appended at their end.

Comment: `@michal` : So to my question :  So, to my question, is there a way to combine `mathml` and externalization? Also externalization excludes the usage of the package `tex4ebook` in order to produce the epub file? I.e. after externalizing, I would have to use (for example) calibre to output to an epub? or I can use `tex4ebook`? Thanks !!

Comment: @pebox11 sorry I missed your further comments, you must use the full user name, the notification system doesn't work otherwise. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I will post answer to the original question and to the additional question from the comments. I haven't seen these comments when they were posted year ago.

> So, to my question, is there a way to combine mathml and externalization?

Externalization doesn't interfere with MathML, it is just `\includegraphics` from `tex4ht` point of view. The problem with your code is that `sgame` package redefines internal LaTeX commands for table handling and it clashes with `tex4ht`. So we need a proper configuration file to get it to work. As a workaround, it is also possible to convert it to image.

So this is a full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{sgame}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzset{
 external/system call/.add={}                                                
      ; inkscape -z -f "\image.pdf" -l "\image.svg"     
}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
    \tikzexternalize[mode=only graphics]
}{
    \tikzexternalize
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Time axis
    \draw (0,0) -- node[below=1cm] {Time $\to$} (6,0);
    % Emotional axis
    \draw (0,0) -- node[left] {\parbox{2cm}{\centering $\uparrow$ \\     Emotional \\ intensity}} (0,4);
    % Time ticks
    \foreach \x [count=\j] in {0.2,3,4.5,6} {
        \draw (\x,0) coordinate (t\j) -- (\x,-0.1cm) node[below] (tt\j)     {Time \j};
    }
    \node[below] at (tt1.south) {(Emotional event)};
    % Curves
    \draw (t1) .. controls +(1,2) .. node[above right] {Experienced} (t2);
    \draw[dashed] (t1) .. controls +(1,4) .. node[above right]    {Predicted} (t4);
\end{tikzpicture} 

Some equation:

\begin{equation} \label{eu_eqn}
  e^{\pi i} + 1 = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[tbh]\hspace*{\fill}
 \begin{game}{2}{2}[$t_1=S$] & $F$ & $NF$\\
$F$ &$1$, -$2$ &$2$, -$1$\\ $NF$ &-$1$, $2$ &$0, 0$ \\
\end{game}
\hspace*{10mm}
\begin{game}{2}{2}[$t_1=W$] & $F$ & $NF$\\ $F$
&-$1,1$ &$2$, -$1$ \\ $NF$ &$0, 2$ &$0, 0$\\ 
\end{game}\hspace*{\fill}%
\caption[]{\textit{A game with incomplete information}} 
\end{figure}    

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  And what about & normal table?\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

We set basic `externalization` stuff in the preamble. We can't get rid of the disambiguation for `\tikzexternalize`, unfortunately.

The config file contains code for `SVG` inclusion, `tex4ht` configuration for the externalization and request for conversion of `game` environment to picture:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml}
\makeatletter
\Configure{graphics*}  
         {svg}{  
          {\Configure{Needs}{File: \Gin@base.svg}\Needs{}}
          \Picture[\csname a:GraphicsAlt\endcsname]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.svg \csname a:Gin-dim\endcsname}%  
         }  
\makeatother

\ConfigureEnv{game}{\Picture+{}}{\EndPicture}{}{}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    tex4ht inc/.style={
        /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
            \includegraphics[]{##1.svg}%
        }
    }
}
\tikzset{tex4ht inc}
\EndPreamble
```

You can compile the document using

```
tex4ebook -f epub3 -c mycfg.cfg filename.tex
```

This is the result:
[image]