# Latex to html : how to add rules like `\subsubsubsection` for htlatex / TeX4ht?

Tags: tex4ht, html, latex2html

I added some rules on my repport in order to add `\subsubsubsection`.

On below the **MWE** :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,french]{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}




\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

\newcounter{subsubsubsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}} % optional; useful if paragraphs are to be numbered

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{6}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\@addtoreset{subsubsubsection}{section}
\@addtoreset{subsubsubsection}{subsection}
\@addtoreset{subsubsubsection}{subsubsection}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}




\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\pagebreak

\section{test}
\subsubsubsection{test11}
\subsubsubsection{test12}
\subsubsubsection{test13}

\section{test2}
\subsubsubsection{test21}
\subsubsubsection{test22}
\subsubsubsection{test23}


\end{document}
```

However, when running htlatex on texmaker (separate HTML page), this `\subsubsubsection` rule is not recognized.

**Question 1)** How can I fix it please ?

**Question 2)** Furthermore, is there a way to include/export tikz pictures on the HTML ?

Comment: regarding tikz to svg conversion, you can use http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35154/2891, or for better output use this method using externalization: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158921/2891

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether using `\subsubsubsection` is a good idea, but anyway. Move `\subsubsubsection` definition to its own package, `subsubsub.sty`:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

\newcounter{subsubsubsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}} % optional; useful if paragraphs are to be numbered

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{6}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\@addtoreset{subsubsubsection}{section}
\@addtoreset{subsubsubsection}{subsection}
\@addtoreset{subsubsubsection}{subsubsection}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
```

now define `tex4ht` configuration file for this package `subsubsub.4ht`:

```
\NewSection\subsubsubsection{\thesubsubsubsection}
\Configure{subsubsubsection}
    {}{}
    {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\addtocounter{subsubsubsection}{1}\HCode{<h4>}\thesubsubsubsection\quad}
    {\HCode{</h4>}}
```

this declares `\subsubsubsection` as sectioning command and new configure hook `subsubsubsection` is created. With `\Configure{subsubsubsection}` you can configure appearance of this section.

Now you need to include `subsubsub` package in your document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,french]{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{subsubsub}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\pagebreak

\section{test}
\subsubsubsection{test11}
\subsubsubsection{test12}
\subsubsubsection{test13}

\section{test2}
\subsubsubsection{test21}
\subsubsubsection{test22}
\subsubsubsection{test23}


\end{document}
```

after compilation with

```
 htlatex filename xhtml
```

this is the result

[image]

generated html:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<!--http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd-->  
<html xml:lang="fr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)" /> 
<!-- xhtml,html --> 
<meta name="src" content="oursay.tex" /> 
<meta name="date" content="2014-02-25 13:44:00" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="oursay.css" /> 
</head><body 
>

   <h2 class="likechapterHead"><a 
 id="x1-1000"></a>Table des matières</h2> <div class="tableofcontents">
   &#x00A0;<span class="sectionToc" >0.1 <a 
href="#x1-20001" id="QQ2-1-2">test</a></span>
<br />   &#x00A0;<span class="sectionToc" >0.2 <a 
href="#x1-60002" id="QQ2-1-6">test2</a></span>
   </div>

<a 
 id="x1-1001r1"></a>
<h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">0.1   </span> <a 
 id="x1-20001"></a>test</h3>
   <h4>0.1.0.0.1   <a 
 id="x1-30000.1.0.0.1"></a>test11</h4>
   <h4>0.1.0.0.2   <a 
 id="x1-40000.1.0.0.2"></a>test12</h4>
   <h4>0.1.0.0.3   <a 
 id="x1-50000.1.0.0.3"></a>test13</h4>
<a 
 id="x1-5001r2"></a>
<h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">0.2   </span> <a 
 id="x1-60002"></a>test2</h3>
   <h4>0.2.0.0.1   <a 
 id="x1-70000.2.0.0.1"></a>test21</h4>
   <h4>0.2.0.0.2   <a 
 id="x1-80000.2.0.0.2"></a>test22</h4>
   <h4>0.2.0.0.3   <a 
 id="x1-90000.2.0.0.3"></a>test23</h4>

</body></html>
```

At this moment, `\subsubsubsection` doesn't appear in the toc, I need to investigate why.

Comment: I see what you mean, but so far it is not working neither by my side.

Comment: @oursay I forgot to mention that you must include package `subsubsub` in your document. does it work now?

Comment: Thanks again. I notice an issue by my side : when using a dept of 4 by my side, it is not working. Why when I move to 5 of depts, it works (but it's not the right numeration) ? Why did you choose : `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}` ?